# Angular ng serve , spa app not loading css background image

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cli

with my Angular 5 application,  I needed to incorporate a CSS file from another team/group.

Angular CLI I reference the CSS file

but in the CSS file it has this `background`

```
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #101010;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: none;
  background: url('/Content/Images/bg-dark.png') top left repeat;
  line-height: 20px;
}
```

Problem is this line  `background: url('/Content/Images/bg-dark.png') top left repeat;`

When I attempt to do ng serve , the spa app cannot locate the image , its looking here:

http://localhost:1203/Content/Images/bg-dark.png

My index.html page is located at

```
\src\index.html
```

This image referenced in the css (which is done is standard angular CLI file)

```
\src\css\Content\images\bg-dark.png
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please use [tag:angularjs] for question about angularjs v1.x (Already removed that tag)

Answer (score 0):

In your path ./css/Content/images/bg-dark.png 
The other way to do it is to put it in your assets folder. It is easier to access just by the name of the file.

Comment: is the assets folder protected from routing / spa   ?

Comment: I invite you to check the angular cli structure

Answer (score 0):

By having a "/" at the beginning of your path, you are specifying an absolute path, where you actually want a relative path. You can do this by instead using `/Content/images/bg-dark.png` or alternatively specifying the full absolute path `/src/css/Content/images/bg-dark.png`

Comment: not working ,   in chrome dev tools i get 404    http://localhost:1203/src/css/Content/Images/bg-dark.png 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I just fixed the casing in my paths in my answer. Generally it's a good idea to keep your paths and folder names all lower case, and they do matter. Your image in the css you mentioned is at `...\Content\images` but the path I had (that I took from snippet had a capital on images `...\Content\Images`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `/src/css/Content/images/bg-dark.png` but be sure to use the correct case of directory names in the path (ie: don't use /Images/ use /images/